# Cuda: Compact and result size

Tags: cuda

I am attempting to use CUDA to find the distance between objects with 3D coordinates. That said, I am only interested in 2 types of objects. The objects are represented as numbers in an array. For this question I am only interested in getting the positions of the first type of object (a user specified number) in the object array.

To that end I'm currently trying to pass this list and a results list to my device and have the device check if each location in the array is the specified number (representing the first object) - and if it is, place that array location in a results array to be returned to the host.

As an example input, suppose I have:

```
int objectArray[10] = { 1, 11, 7, 2, 7, 23, 6, 6, 9, 11 };

int results[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

and I'm trying to get the positions of all the instances of 7 (and preferably, a returned value stating how many instances of 7 were found)
ie. (with instances of 7 being present in position 2 and 4 of `objectArray`)

```
results={2,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

resultCount=2;
```

I'm fairly new to Cuda and if anyone knows how this is done, I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: This should be pretty easy with [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using thrust as @RobertCrovella already pointed out.
The following example uses [`thrust::copy_if`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#gac1155c0eddf9d5145776bd454732415b) to copy all of elements' indices for which the condition ("equals 7")  is fulfilled.  [`thrust::counting_iterator`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/classthrust_1_1counting__iterator.html) is used to avoid creating the sequence of indices explicitly.

```
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    int objectArray[N] = { 1, 11, 7, 2, 7, 23, 6, 6, 9, 11 };
    int results[N]={0};

    int* end = thrust::copy_if(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), thrust::make_counting_iterator(N), objectArray, results, _1 == 7);

    thrust::copy(results, results+N, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl << "result count = " << end-results << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
2 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
result count = 2
```

Comment: The code is valid and a good demonstration, but it does not actually use the GPU.

Comment: @RobertCrovella you are right, I just copied the input data from the question. changing to thrust::device_vector is hopefully possible for the OP.

Comment: Works great. I've been trying copy_if for a while, but couldn't get it to do this (or a simpler task). I'm actually dealing with 10 GB worth of pdb protein files, so I cannot specify the object array sizes in advanced. Pretty sure I'll be able to pull it off with thrust vectors though. Thanks for taking the time to responding.