# Cuda::thrust: Performing compact operation with Device_vector

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm still fairly new to Cuda and while a stackoverflow user gave me a  descriptive example on how to use thrust::copy_if to compact an array of known size on the host (as I worded my question badly), I've been unable to convert the approach to use device_vectors (to deal with inputted arrays of unknown size on the device).

I'm attempting to generate a compacted list of the positions of all the elements in a vector which match a user specified predicate. The working example I was given is:

```
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    int objectArray[N] = { 1, 11, 7, 2, 7, 23, 6, 6, 9, 11 };
    int results[N]={0};

    int* end = thrust::copy_if(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), thrust::make_counting_iterator(N), objectArray, results, _1 == 7);

    thrust::copy(results, results+N, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl << "result count = " << end-results << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to modify the code to use device vectors (and compute on the device) as follows:

```
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int soughtElement=7;

reader.open("Numeric_1a40Coords.txt");
reader >> sizeOfProteinChain; //This returns the size of the input
reader.close();

thrust::host_vector<int> Host_names(sizeOfProteinChain);
thrust::host_vector<int> Host_results;
ImportNumericNameValues("Numeric_1a40Coords.txt", Host_names); //This populates the vector with "sizeOfProteinChain" number of elements

thrust::device_vector<int> Device_names = Host_Names;
thrust::device_vector<int> Device_results = Host_results;

Host_results = thrust::copy_if(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), thrust::make_counting_iterator(sizeOfProteinChain), Device_names, Device_results, _1 == soughtElement);

host_results=device_results;

for (int i=0;i<sizeOfProteinChain;i++)
cout<< host_results[i]<<" ";
cout<<endl;

/*Not sure how to get the resulting number of compacted position elements with device vectors instead of pointer arrays*/
```

I get errors stating that:

> class "thrust::device_vector>" has no member
>   "iterator_category"

and:

> no instance of overloaded function "thrust::copy_if" matches the
>   argument list

I've been stuck on this for a while and any suggestions on how to correct those errors, or more accurately convert the above sample, would be greatly appreciated. My previous question on this matter [can be found here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013160/cuda-compact-and-result-size)

Comment: You were given a nice code that can be copied, compiled and run.  In your code you've elected to strip out `int main()` and who knows what else.  How is that helpful to others?  Why not provide a short, complete code?

Comment: Will do so in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to read the [thrust quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).

This will get you in trouble:

```
thrust::host_vector<int> Host_results;
```

that creates a vector of zero size.  Later when you do this:

```
thrust::device_vector<int> Device_results = Host_results;
```

You've created another vector of zero size.  Although these will not create compile errors, if you try to use these (e.g. by copying something into them) without a proper size allocation, you're going to have trouble at run-time.

This is also wrong:

```
Host_results = thrust::copy_if(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), thrust::make_counting_iterator(sizeOfProteinChain), Device_names, Device_results, _1 == soughtElement);
```

The [return value](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#ga36d9d6ed8e17b442c1fd8dc40bd515d5) of the `thrust::copy_if` function is an *iterator*.  You cannot assign it to a vector.  A vector is not the same as an iterator.  `Host_results` is a vector.

Not sure what this is:

```
host_results=device_results;
```

Do you actually have a variable or vector somewhere that also begins with a lower case `h`?  Because `host_results` is not the same as `Host_results`

Here's a complete worked example demonstrating how to do thrust::copy_if on device vectors of arbitrary length:

```
$ cat t808.cu
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <iostream>

#define COPY_VAL 7

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main(){

  int objectArray[] = { 1, 11, 7, 2, 7, 23, 6, 6, 9, 11 };
  int dsize = sizeof(objectArray)/sizeof(int);
  int results[dsize];

  thrust::device_vector<int> d_obj(objectArray, objectArray+dsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_res(dsize);

  int resultCount = thrust::copy_if(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), thrust::make_counting_iterator(dsize), d_obj.begin(),  d_res.begin(), (_1 == COPY_VAL)) - d_res.begin();
  thrust::copy(d_res.begin(), d_res.end(), results);
  std::cout << "resultCount = " << resultCount << std::endl << "results: " << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_res.begin(), d_res.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}



$ nvcc -o t808 t808.cu
$ ./t808
resultCount = 2
results:
2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
$
```

Comment: Thanks, your code and that guide were both very helpful - and I've got my stuff working :). The variable names in my actual program are filled with content specific words, so stuff like Host_results vs host results were just terrible clarity editing on my part. Not setting Host_results side was a mistake. I'd like to ask something if you still around though,  As Host_results is a Host_vector and Device_results is a device vector, is I want to perform several operations on my vector on the host, cant i use  host_results=device_results; to put my results back on the host for processing?

Comment: Have you read the thrust quick start guide I suggested?  Because I think your question is answered there.  "As this example shows, the  =  operator can be used to copy a  host_vector  to a  device_vector  (or vice-versa). The  =  operator can also be used to copy  host_vector  to  host_vector  or  device_vector  to  device_vector "  There are generally multiple ways to skin the cat when programming.  Just because I've shown or chosen one method does not mean others are not possible.  The problem I was pointing out with your usage of `=` was the zero-length vectors involved.

Comment: I did see that in the quick start guide. I was just hoping to confirm that final detail with you - as the previous conceptual bungle I made resulted in this rather embarrassing second question.